# link to another page in promp in javascript in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, prompt

how to link to another page in prompt in javascript in asp.net

in else i want to link another page

```
function  a()
{
    var s = prompt("hello");
    if (s != 123) {
        alert("enter number correctly");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you look up "Javascript redirect"? - `window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [window.location.href](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) to open other page in else part.

```
function  a()
{
    var s = prompt("hello");
    if (s != 123) {
        alert("enter number correctly");
        return true;
    }
    else
        window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; 
}
```

Comment: Can you exlain what does not work? what error you get? Also add your teleric control with code showing interaction of it with javascript.